# Style manager not working to batch style group in QGIS 2.0.1

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, symbology, style, batch

I am trying to apply batch styling to a group of layers using the style manager by setting the conditions, but the symbology does not seem to be applying. This is considering the multiqml plugin is not ready for QGIS 2.0 yet. In any case, is it possible to also upon adding vector data, specify a preloaded style, i.e. qml style descriptor or sld when importing them into the layer work-space?

For that matter, how do you enable batch labeling for a group?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I use key shortcuts to copy layer styles then paste them ('c' then 'v', which is quick at least), but we need a better solution!

Comment: Actually that's pretty much what I did when I was still working on it, but I concur.